# Loop in list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary, it's a list of books, it came from a JSON file. I have an another dictionary, it's empty word and a number. If the title of the book start with, I want to add a new key to the dictionary and the value of that key will be the number. I've the way.

This one give me : `name 'j' is not defined`

```
import json

with open('book.json', 'r') as f:
    books_dict = json.load(f)

empty_word = {
    'The ' : '4',
    'An ' : '3',
}

for book in books_dict:
    if any(book["Title"].startswith(k,0) for k, j in empty_word.items()):
        book['number'] = j
        books_list.append(book)
```

This other one just do nothing, I have to interrupt and it seem the be this line the problem :

```
import json

with open('book.json', 'r') as f:
    books_dict = json.load(f)

empty_word = {
    'The ' : '4',
    'An ' : '3',
}

for book in books_dict:
    for i, k in empty_word.items():
        if book["Title"].startswith(i,0):
            book['number'] = k
            books_dict.append(book)
```

I'm a noob and clearly I'm missing something. First time here, if someone can guide me!

Comment: The first example is not going to work because `j` is not in scope where you are trying to use it. The second one is strange in that you are appending to `books_dict` rather than `books_list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is a scope error. You're attempting to use `j`, but `j` is only defined for your call to the `any` function:

```
any(book["Title"].startswith(k,0) for k, j in empty_word.items())
```

This can be solved by splitting this into several expressions:

```
for k, j in empty_word.items():
    if book["Title"].startswith(k,0):
        book['number'] = j
        books_list.append(book)
```

The second is because you are appending to an iterable *while you're iterating over it*. This is almost universally bad, but your case looks like a typo. Try changing the last line to `books_list.append(book)`.

Comment: The problem was that I was iterating over it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)